# Associating DispForm with with an spfield item

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom view of a list that doesn't include the "Title" field, I need to associate the display from with another spfield, how do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved by setting the `LinkToItemAllowed` and `ListItemMenuAllowed` properties of the spfield to `SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;`

Answer (score 0):

Although not the nicest but a simple SPD workflow that populates a custom column of type Hyperlink/Picture with the DisplayForm URL. And then you can display this column into your respective view.

However, what's the reason you want to do this? You don't have the value in title? You can use the Title(linked to item) instead of Title(linked to Edit Menu). You may want to verify the names though as what I have put in terms of paranthesis might not be exact.

Comment: System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();  
                viewFields.Add("First Name");  
                viewFields.Add("Middle");  
                viewFields.Add("Last Name");  
                empList.Views.Add("Employee View", viewFields, "", 100, false, true);
                empList.Update();
                SPField firstName =  empList.Fields["First Name"];
                //I need to make firstName have the link to dispform               
                firstName.Update();

Comment: Finally figured it out.                                          Achieved by setting the LinkToItemAllowed and ListItemMenuAllowed properties of the spfield to SPField.ListItemMenuState.Required;